# Not able to update text tab value using updateTabs API

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Here is the scenario i am working with. I am trying to update the text tabs value in the envelope. Here is the sample cofeescript code.

```
envelopesApi.listTabs(@accountId, envelopeId, recipientId).then((tabs) =>          
    updatedTabs =
      textTabs: []
      
    for tab in tabs.textTabs
      if data[tab.tabLabel]
        updatedTabs.textTabs.push { tabId: tab.tabId, value: data[tab.tabLabel] }
    
    envelopesApi.updateTabs(@accountId, envelopeId, recipientId, { templateTabs: docusign.TemplateTabs.constructFromObject(updatedTabs) }).then((tabs) =>
      console.log 'tabs: ' + JSON.stringify(tabs)
      cb null
    )
).catch((err) ->
  console.log err
)
```

The above call at updateTabs is throwing me the following error.

```
{
    status: 400,
    text: '{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY","message":"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. No tabs specified."}',
    method: 'PUT',
    path: '/restapi/v2.1/accounts/2fc0822d-782d-43d6-b217-79d23aaed3a3/envelopes/35fc12b2-621f-412d-99c5-d8f3ab01c5ee/recipients/2/tabs'
},
```

Am i missing something here? Appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: what does your console.log 'tabs: ' + JSON.stringify(tabs) show?

Comment: It failed before getting to that line.

Comment: can you move this line before making the API call and see? I'm trying to determine what is the JSON you're sending to the API...

Comment: i figured out the issue, the request body for updateTabs api should be 'tabs' instead of 'templateTabs'. thanks for the help

Comment: For the future, you can always step into the SDK code and see where things are going wrong. Just find the file under node-modules folder under docusign-esign and put a breakpoint in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
envelopesApi.listTabs(@accountId, envelopeId, recipientId).then((tabs) =>          
    updatedTabs =
      textTabs: []
      
    for tab in tabs.textTabs
      if data[tab.tabLabel]
        updatedTabs.textTabs.push { tabId: tab.tabId, value: data[tab.tabLabel] }
    
    envelopesApi.updateTabs(@accountId, envelopeId, recipientId, { tabs: docusign.TemplateTabs.constructFromObject(updatedTabs) }).then((tabs) =>
      console.log 'tabs: ' + JSON.stringify(tabs)
      cb null
    )
).catch((err) ->
  console.log err
)
```